# If projections $P$ and $Q$ are commutative, then $P+Q-PQ$ projects onto $\text{im}P+\text{im}Q$

Tags: functional-analysis, map-projections

**Projection**: Suppose $X$ is a normed vector space, we define a projection $P$ as a *linear* and *continuous* mapping from X to X, such that *$P^2 = P$*.

**im$P$**: the image of $P$

**commutative**: $PQ=QP$

The question is: If $P$ and $Q$ are commutative projections, $P + Q − PQ$ projects onto $\text{im} P + \text{im}Q$.(Here by "onto", I mean "surjective".)

Comment: This is a problem from Joseph Muscat's *Functional Analysis An Introduction to Metric Spaces, Hilbert Spaces, and Banach Algebras*, P131, Exercise 8.17, 2.

Comment: HInt: first check by computation whether $P+Q-PQ$ is a projection.  If so, what is its image?  Clearly $im (P+Q-PQ) \subset im P + im Q$.  What happens if you apply the projection to something in $im P + im Q$?

Comment: @JoshKeneda That is exactly what I want to show, but I don't know how to prove $\text{im}P + \text{im}Q \subset \text{im}(P+Q-PQ)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove that $P+Q-PQ $ is a projection:
\begin{align}
(P+Q-PQ)^2
&=P^2+Q^2+P^2Q^2+2PQ-2P^2Q-2PQ^2\\
&=P+Q+PQ+2PQ-2PQ-2PQ\\
&=P+Q-PQ
\end{align}
For every $ x,y\in X $ we have
\begin{align}
(P+Q-PQ)(Px+Qy)
&=Px+PQy+PQx+Qy-PQx-PQy\\
&=Px+Qy
\end{align}
thus proving $\newcommand\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\Im (P+Q-PQ)=\Im P+\Im Q $.